# What are the differences between git clone --shared and --reference?

Tags: git

After reading the documentation, I still don't really understand what the
differences are between `--shared` and `--reference <repo>`. They seem so similar.

1. **What are the differences between the** `--shared` **and**
   `--reference <repo>` **options?**
2. **Can they be used to save drive space when making multiple local clones of
   another local clone?**
3. **Can each local clone have a different branch checked-out?**

**Note:** I'm aware that I can use multiple shallow clones with truncated
history by using `git clone --depth <depth>`, but each clone still has to
duplicate ***at least some*** history  in order to do that, so I was
thinking that maybe it's not the most optimal way to save drive space (though it
is better than nothing).

### Background

Sometimes I like to have more than one checkout of my working copy in a
repository, so I create multiple clones, where each clone has its own checkout.

However, I don't really need the whole history with each clone, just the most
up-to-date versions of my branches, so I could possibly save a lot of drive
space by having each clone use the tag, commit, tree, and blob objects from the
original local clone (for example, via symlinks for something).

### `git clone` documentation

I checked [the `git clone` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-clone.html) to see if there's anything I
can use.

#### `--shared`

I saw that there's a `--shared` option:

> When the repository to clone is on the local machine, instead of using hard
>   links, automatically setup `.git/objects/info/alternates` to share the objects
>   with the source repository. The resulting repository starts out without any
>   object of its own.

This looks like it ***might*** be useful for helping me to save drive space
with multiple clones that have different checkouts, since each clone shares
objects with the original local clone.

#### `--reference <repository>`

Then I also saw the `--reference <repository>` option:

> If the reference repository is on the local machine, automatically setup
>   `.git/objects/info/alternates` to obtain objects from the reference
>   repository. Using an already existing repository as an alternate will require
>   fewer objects to be copied from the repository being cloned, reducing network
>   and local storage costs.
>
> **NOTE:** see the NOTE for the `--shared` option.

This says that it will reduce local storage costs, so this might be useful as
well.

Comment: @user3348022 cool, I saw [this from Google search](http://lists-archives.com/git/505518-clarify-git-clone-local-shared-reference.html), but I couldn't figure out how to navigate the archaic interface in order to find the first couple of replies. If you want to summarize the relevant parts of that and add it as answer, you might earn some EPIC upvotes and repz! `:D`

Comment: @user3348022 also, that email you linked still doesn't clarify enough to me about why I would want to use `--shared` vs `--reference`. Is the only difference that when you use `--shared`, the origin is the local repo being cloned, while with `--reference`, the origin is the remote repo being cloned?

Comment: @John - I'm a little confused. The answers you linked to say that --reference implies --shared. But DoubleWord's answer says that --shared does not copy the objects, whereas --reference does copy the objects. That hardly seems like an "implies" relationship.  That also makes --reference seem much less dangerous than --shared. Can you clarify at all?

Comment: the 'lists-archives.com' link led me to clickbait, this narkive link was still good: https://git.vger.kernel.narkive.com/TxZNFARz/clarify-clone-local-shared-reference, I recommend reading as there's some interesting interactions when using these options

Answer (score 15):

Both options update `.git/objects/info/alternates` to point to the source repository, which could be dangerous hence the warning note is present on both options in documentation.

The `--shared` option does not copy the objects into the clone. This is the main difference.

The `--reference` uses an *additional* repository parameter. Using `--reference` still copies the objects into destination during the clone, however you are specifying objects be copied from an existing source when they are already available in the reference repository. This can reduce network time and IO from the source repository by passing the path to a repository on a faster/local device using `--reference`

*See for yourself*

Create a `--shared` clone and a `--reference` clone. Count the objects in each using `git count-objects -v`. You'll notice the shared clone has no objects, and the reference clone has the same number of objects as the source. Further, notice the size difference of each in your file system. If you were to move the source, and test `git log` in both shared and reference repositories, the log is unavailable in the shared clone, but works fine in the reference clone.

Comment: So what's the difference between using `--reference` and using a normal `git clone`

Comment: @YahyaUddin: the difference occurs when cloning a *non-local* repository. Without `--reference` this downloads all the objects over the network. With `--reference` this gets the object IDs over the network, then checks to see if those object IDs are available locally. If they *are* available locally it skips the download step. If they are *not* available locally it downloads as usual. The end result is that `git clone --reference` is *faster* (how much faster depends on how up-to-date the local reference is). (But see also `--dissociate`.)

Comment: "--shared" can really only be used when cloning a local repo ; whereas "--reference" is mostly useful when cloning a distant over-the-network repo for which we already have some objects available in a local repo. The usecases are thus different, and I think this answer is misleading

Answer (score 8):

The [link in the comments to your question](http://lists-archives.com/git/494327-clarify-git-clone-local-shared-reference.html) is really a clearer answer: `--reference` implies `--shared`. **The point of `--reference` is to optimise network I/O during the initial clone of a remote repository.**

Contrary to the answer above, I find that the `--shared` and `--reference` repositories -- from the same source -- have the same size and both have zero objects. Of course, if you use `--reference` for some other repository which is based off a common source, the size and objects will reflect the difference between the repositories. **Note** that in both cases we are not saving space in the work tree, only the `.git/objects`.

There is some nuance to maintaining this setup going forward - read the thread for more details. Essentially it sounds like the two should be treated as public repositories, with care around history re-writing in the presence of repacking/pruning/garbage collection.

The workflow around maintaining an optimal disk-space usage after the initial clone seems to be:

1. pull source
2. repack source
3. pull secondary
4. `git gc` in secondary

Probably best to read the discussion in that thread though.

You can add an alternate to an existing repository by putting the absolute path to the source's `objects` directory into `secondary/.git/objects/info/alternates` and running `git gc` (many people use `git repack -a -d -l`, which is done by `git gc`).

You can remove an alternate by running `git repack -a -d` (no `-l`) in the secondary and then removing the line from the `alternates` file. As described in the thread, it is possible to have more than one alternate.

I've not used this much myself, so I don't know how error-prone it is to manage.

Comment: The dangers of `--shared` are also mentioned at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2350996/how-can-one-safely-use-a-shared-object-database-in-git

Answer (score 3):

The [link in the comments](http://ww1.lists-archives.com/?subid1=6c2e8df2-79bb-11ea-8cdf-c72c328a4f67) to your question is now dead.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/git-pocket-guide/9781449327507/ch06.html has some great information on the subject. Here is some of what is there:

> first, we make a bare clone of the remote repository, to be shared
>   locally as a reference repository (hence named “refrep”): 
> $ git clone --bare http://foo/bar.git refrep
>
> Then, we clone the remote again, but this time giving refrep as a
>   reference: 
> $ git clone --reference refrep http://foo/bar.git
>
> The key difference between this and the --shared option is that you
>   are still tracking the remote repository, not the refrep clone. When
>   you pull, you still contact http://foo/, but you don’t need to wait
>   for it to send any objects that are already stored locally in refrep;
>   when you push, you are updating the branches and other refs of the foo
>   repository directly.
>
> Of course, as soon as you and others start pushing new commits, the
>   reference repository will become out of date, and you’ll start to lose
>   some of the benefit. Periodically, you can run git fetch --all in
>   refrep to pull in any new objects. A single reference repository can
>   be a cache for the objects of any number of others; just add them as
>   remotes in the reference:
>
> $ git remote add zeus http://olympus/zeus.git 
> $ git fetch --all zeus