# Can I clone a remote git repository but reference a local repository for efficiency?

Tags: windows, git, git-clone

I have my local development repo on Windows at `C:\Dev\myrepo`, that was cloned from the remote repo is at `git@githost.com:myrepo.git`. I’m getting ready to deploy it and I'd like to clone the repo in a different location, `C:\Publish\myrepo` so that it's completely clean.

What I'd like to do is:

1. Clone the remote repo but leverage the existing local repo so that the entire repo doesn't have to be downloaded needlessly.
2. After the clone is complete, I don’t want there to be any connection between the two local repos.

I've read a few things about --reference and --bare and --share, and it is hard to be certain whether things are going to really do what I expect them to do.

Will the following command do what I want?

```
cd /c/Publish
git clone --reference /c/Dev/myrepo git@githost.com:myrepo.git
```

Comment: @JakeGould How is that related to the question?

Comment: You have too much fantasy ;) Btw, capistrano is ok but far from great. (imo) A simple shell script can be crafted faster, is more powerful and gains full control over the deploy process. However, this question is not about web application deployment.

Comment: `s/gains/allows to gain/` ...

Comment: Possibly related: [What are the differences between git clone --shared and --reference?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23304374/456814).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can follow these steps:

```sh
cd '/c/Publish'

# Clone the local repository. origin points now to '/c/Dev/myrepo'
git clone '/c/Dev/myrepo'

# Remove the local origin
git remote rm origin

# Add the remote origin
git remote add origin git@githost.com:myrepo.git

# Assuming the master branch was cloned, 
# you need to set that up to track the remote master
git branch --set-upstream-to=origin/master master

# Tracking for other branches will be set up automatically with a pull
git pull
```

Comment: It could be done this way, true. But what I really want is a pure copy of the code as would be yielded by a clone from the remote repo. The thought of reproducing the .gitignore rules for xcopy gives me a headache. And with all the features that are built in to git, this seems a very fair question.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why would you "reproduce the .gitignore rules for xcopy"?

Comment: Because the code base stored in C:\Dev\myrepo has a bajillion artifacts from compiling, running, etc., that I don't want to interfere with the deploy.

Comment: Ok, then use my first suggest. I've rolled back my answer

Comment: @hek2mgl - This is exactly what I first thought to do but I thought maybe there was more implied by clone that would have to be undone.  Is removing the remote and adding the correct remote really all there is to it?

Comment: I don't know a better solution. Also it is quite simple to achieve.

Comment: What I ended up doing is a variation of your other answer, @hek2mgl.  First, I clone git@githost.com:myrepo.git at C:\dev\myrepo for development. For deployment, I cloned git@githost.com:myrepo.git at C:\publish\pure\myrepo. Then, whenever I want to deploy I just pull at pure\myrepo, copy that to C:\publish\build\myrepo, where I build, deploy, and delete when done. The cycle continues without ever having to clone again. This is different than what's asked in the question, but is worth noting, I think.